# JavaScript For loop parseFloat or parseInt

Tags: javascript, parsing, for-loop

Hey guys I have some code here that is supposed to add up all the valid data then total it.

```
if (myErrorFlag != "Y") 
{
   for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
   {
      AmountNumber = 'amount' + i;
      AmountValue = parseInt($(AmountNumber).value);
      $('total').value += parseInt(AmountValue);
   }

}
```

What i want is for the loop to get all values that are entered and total them.

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: Also what does the markup look like

Comment: I don't understand this code. What is $(AmountNumber)?

Comment: Add some more details to your question like what is AmountNumber-a variable,string or int?

Comment: Also note that if you pass an `id` to jQuery selector method, you need to prefix the `id` with `#`'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, even though you are `parseInt`ing, you are still concatenating:

```
$('total').value = $('total').value + parseInt(AmountValue);
```

That's what your `+=` is effectively doing. And an input's value is a string.

Try this instead:

```
var total = 0, i;
for( i=1; i<=4; i++) {
    total += parseInt(document.getElementById('amount'+i).value,10);
}
document.getElementById('total').value = total;
```

Comment: This works great, but just a few questions.. what does the i represents in var total = 0, i; and why is there a 10 after the ('amount'+i).value,10); @Niet the Dark Absol

Comment: @user2872778 `10` refers to decimal number system.

Comment: `var total=0, i` defines some local variables, ie. avoids polluting the global scope, which is very important. In this case, the `i` is the iterator, and `total` is a running total AS AN INT, rather than saving it somewhere else as a string. As for the `10`, it's as thefourtheye says. The second argument to `parseInt` is NOT optional.

Comment: Thank you for the brief explanation!

Comment: I would accept this as a great answer but i don't have enought reputation on this site to do so...